# Fill a region of an image based on inequality equations

Tags: python, matplotlib, inequality

I want to plot a filled-in region on a 2D plot using `matplotlib` in python. The implicit region is defined by,

```
def f(x,y):
    return sqrt(2*x*y)-x-y
```

I want to add to an existing image a filled-in region in the XY plane defined by the two inequalities,

```
sqrt(x**2+y**2)-2<=f(x,y) && f(x,y)>=1
```

To be clear, I want to plot a region defined by all (x,y) values that satisfy the above inequalities. I have tried getting it to work with `pyplot.contour` but I can't get it to work. What is the correct approach?

EDIT: Below is an example image of my desired output:
[image]

This is an image of a planet casting a shadow on its rings based on its positioning with its star. I created that image in Mathematica, and now I need to create something equivalent in python. I have a plot of the planet and the rings already, and I am trying to add the shadow.

The shadow is defined by two inequalities and resides in the XY plane. The equations I gave above are highly simplified for convenience; I do not need help with the math, only implementing it in a plot.

In the python version, I also want the shadow to be a filled-in region that resides in the XY plane.

Comment: Do you have an example of the desired output?

Comment: @Kefeng91, I have added an image of what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directly using a contour plot will have problems because the function is only defined in two of the four quadrants. Therefore it is advisable to first transform the inequalities into a binary array over a grid.

To plot this you may use an `imshow` plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = lambda x,y : np.sqrt(2*x*y)-x-y
g = lambda x,y : np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)-2

d = np.linspace(-2,2,2000)
x,y = np.meshgrid(d,d)

im = plt.imshow( ((g(x,y)<=f(x,y)) & (f(x,y)<=1)).astype(int) , 
                extent=(x.min(),x.max(),y.min(),y.max()),origin="lower", cmap="Greys")

plt.show()
```

[image]

You may equally use a contourf plot; here, in order to get the contour close to the binary values, it may make sense to use two levels close to `1`. It'll also require to define an all-black colormap.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

f = lambda x,y : np.sqrt(2*x*y)-x-y
g = lambda x,y : np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)-2

d = np.linspace(-2,2,2000)
x,y = np.meshgrid(d,d)
z = ((g(x,y)<=f(x,y)) & (f(x,y)<=1)).astype(int) 

cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(["k","k"])
plt.contourf(x,y,z, [0.99999, 1.00001], cmap=cmap)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get this to work. It is capable of producing the correct shadow as a standalone plot, but it does not add nicely to my existing 3D projection. I need the shadow to be properly represented in a 3D projection from any viewpoint.

Comment: I currently cannot imagine how a 2D shaddow would look in 3D, but I edited the question to include a contour solution. Contours can be drawn in 3D plots as well.

Comment: @ahle6481: maybe you could give more detail about how you go from the 3D model to the image and how is this related to Matplotlib, or how the 3D model is build using Python?... however it seems to me that this is another problem, then another question...